# Extract specific positions from a char array

Tags: performance, beginner, c, strings

I have two arrays:

```
char input[] = "ughIuytLikeretC";
```

and

```
bool mask[] = {
    false, false, false, true, false,
    false, false, true, true, true,
    true, false, false, false, true,
};
```

My function takes these two arrays and returns the characters in input whose positions are true in mask such that in this example, the result being ILikeC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *filtArray(char input[], bool mask[], char *filtered) {
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
        filtered[j] = input[i];
        j += mask[i];
        }

    filtered[j] = 0;
    return filtered;
}
```

`filtArray` will run on billions of "input" strings of constant length and "mask" will be the same for all "input"s.

Comment: It's bad practice to write data to a result array that shouldn't be there. You write the contents to `filtered` regardless of if it should be there or not, then overwrite it. Avoid this. Suppose there is no correct data - you will then corrupt the result array. I would also avoid using booleans for arithmetic, it's quite ugly and hard to read.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not clear on what you mean when you say the array "shouldn't be there."  Seems to me it should always exist since that result is the point of calling the function in the first place.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your sample code.

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that `mask` be an array of booleans? Because that's quite inefficient. You really should be using a binary mask in an integer.

Answer (score 4):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Provide complete code to reviewers

This is not so much a change to the code as a change in how you present it to other people.  Without the full context of the code and an example of how to use it, it takes more effort for other people to understand your code.  This affects not only code reviews, but also maintenance of the code in the future, by you or by others.  One good way to address that is by the use of comments.  Another good technique is to include test code showing how your code is intended to be used.  Here's the test `main` I used for your code:

```
int main() {
    const char *input[2] = {
        "ughIuytLikeretC", 
        "xxxExxxdwarxxxd",
    };
    const bool mask[] = {
        false, false, false, true, false,
        false, false, true, true, true,
        true, false, false, false, true,
    };
    char filt[100];
    char maskstr[100];
    // create the mask string
    pmask(mask, maskstr);

    printf("Orig: %s\nMask: %s\nFilt: %s\n", input[0], maskstr, filtArray(input[0], mask, filt));
    printf("Orig: %s\nMask: %s\nFilt: %s\n", input[1], maskstr, filtArray(input[1], mask, filt));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        int n = rand() > RAND_MAX/2 ? 1 : 0;
        printf("Orig: %s\nMask: %s\nFilt: %s\n", input[n], maskstr, filtArray(input[n], mask, filt));
    }
}
```

After it applies the function to two strings, it then iterates 10 million times, choosing one or the other test inputs randomly.  This is for testing timing.

### Use `const` where practical

The `filtArray` function does not (and should not) alter either the passed `input` or `mask` arrays and so both of those should be declared `const`.

```
char *filtArray(const char input[], const bool mask[], char *filtered) {
```

### Consider bounds checking

If the input strings have already been validated for length, the function you have is OK, but in general, it's good to make sure there is enough room to copy the masked characters.  If there isn't enough room, that's the recipe for a [buffer overflow vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and must be eliminated, either by the calling routine or by this one.

### Consider a custom copy

If the same mask is used for billions of strings, it would probably make sense to do things differently.  For example, one alternative might look like this:

```
#include <string.h>

char *filtArray(const char input[], char *filtered) {
    memcpy(&filtered[1], &input[7], 4);
    filtered[0] = input[3];
    filtered[5] = input[14];
    filtered[6] = '\0';
    return filtered;
}
```

Note that the `mask` is no longer used in this version, because the code has implemented it implicitly.  This is less flexible but offers better performance.  For 10 million strings on my machine, your original version takes about 1.3 seconds, while the version shown here takes around 1.0 seconds (redirecting the output to `/dev/null` on a Linux machine).

### Use pointers rather than indexing for speed

Pointers are generally a faster way to access elements than using index variables.  For example, your `filtArray` routine could be written like this:

```
char *filtArray(const char *input, const bool *mask, char *filtered) {
    char *beginning = filtered;
    for ( ; *input; ++input, ++mask) {
        if (*mask) {
            *filtered++ = *input;
        }
    }
    *filtered  = '\0';
    return beginning;
}
```

Because you're just beginning, this may seem strange to you, but this kind of use of pointers is a very common idiom in C.

#### Compilers are good, but not quite that good yet

Because there's a tendency to assume the compiler will take care of it, here's compiler output comparison of the two approaches using gcc for ARM using the on-line compiler explorer:  https://godbolt.org/z/Y0TeVX

As can be seen in this case, the generated assembly code for the pointer version is much shorter.  Shorter code is usually faster (and it is in this case according to my testing) but not always.  For those who are expert in compiler design: The typical improvement is as likely to be the elimination of extra live variables as for the use of pointers *per se*, but the effect is nonetheless real.

#### Measured timings

For each of the three variations, original, pointer, and memcpy, here are the measured times for 10 million iterations and the variances of each set of samples and the relative speed measured as the average speed compared with the average speed of the original expressed as a percentage.  With no optimization:

\$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c}
{\bf name}&{\bf avg (s)}&{\bf var (s)}&{\bf relative}\\
\hline
\text{original}&1.344&0.01853&100.00\% \\
\text{pointer}&1.244&0.01193&92.56\% \\
\text{memcpy}&0.998&0.01177&74.26\%
\end{array}\$

With `-O2` optimization:

\$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c}
{\bf name}&{\bf avg (s)}&{\bf var (s)}&{\bf relative}\\
\hline
\text{original}&1.038&0.01462&100.00\% \\
\text{pointer}&1.000&0.00135&96.34\% \\
\text{memcpy}&0.948&0.00692&91.33\%
\end{array}\$

These results were on a 64-bit Linux machine using `gcc` version 8.2.1.  I look forward to seeing other measured timing results.  Time is user time as measured by `time -f %U` (See https://linux.die.net/man/1/time for man page).

Comment: "Pointers are generally a faster way to access elements than using index variables."  This is very subjective. The opposite may as well be true, depending on system. We should not replace indexing with pointer arithmetic unless we have very good reasons - doing so for the sake of performance is pre-mature optimization. To truly optimize for speed, it might be better to drop the bool array in favour of true bit masks.

Comment: It's not actually subjective, but based on *measurement and experience.*  On my machine it's faster, and for many embedded systems compilers (which is what I use often) it's generally faster.  But what matters is whether it's faster for the author of the code.  Only measurement on that system and with real data will tell whether it's faster or not.

Comment: I've added more data and explanation to show why pointers are faster with this code.

Comment: The resulting assembly is still very dependent on compiler as well. Switching to using the intel compiler on godbolt results in indexing generating shorter assembly.

Comment: @pseudonym117 At the risk of stating the obvious, the output assembly is *always* dependent on the compiler.  In the example you mentioned, while there are fewer instructions, the assembled code is both longer and slower with the indexed version vs the pointer version.  (42 bytes vs. 38 bytes for pointer version).  https://godbolt.org/z/Sr1Bsq  It's another example of why we must *measure* rather than guess.

Comment: `if (mask) {
            *filtered++ = *input;
        }` looks wrong.  Perhaps `if (*mask) {
            *filtered++ = *input;
        }`  (Add `*`).   Note: this error negates your code comparison.  As with all performance improvements, insure correct functionality first.

Comment: With code fixed, the 2 alternatives are closer in size.

Comment: The code I timed was correct -- somehow made an error pasting it.  Thanks!  Also, since there seems to be a lot of resistance to the idea, I've posted detailed timing results.  If anybody would like to post other results (or faster code!) I'd like to see the measured results.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiled with no warnings and ran properly on first time which is great.

Let's see what can be improved.

**Style**

The indentation of the code seems a bit weird. I do not know if this is how it looked originally or if it got broken when it was copied here.

Also, it may be worth adding some documentation describing the inputs you are expecting (in your case, 3 arrays of same size, the first one being 0-terminated).

**Do less**

You use the mask only to know whether `j` is to be incremented. Actually, you could rewrite:

```
j += mask[i];
```

as

```
    if (mask[i])
        j++;
```

which is more explicit but less concise.

The real benefic is when you realize than updating `filtered` can be done only when we have `mask[i]`. We can write:

```
    if (mask[i])
    {
        filtered[j] = input[i];
        j++;
    }
```

or the equivalent:

```
    if (mask[i])
        filtered[j++] = input[i];
```

**Null character**

Instead of `filtered[j] = 0;`, you could use the [Null Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) which is equivalent here but more usual and write: `filtered[j] = '\0';`.

**Signature**

I am not sure if it is really useful to have the `filtered` value returned as it is already known by the calling function. Also, `filterArray` may be a better name.

**Going further**

Instead of definining a mask as an array of boolean, you could provide an array with the positions of the characters you are interested in.

In your case, you'd provide something like: `{3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14 }`.

This could be less efficient because we'd perform a smaller number of iterations. Here, we'd iterate over 6 elements instead of 15.

The corresponding mask could be converted manually (which is what I did here) if it is for a known value or you could write a function to pre-process the mask. This seems to be relevant in your case as the same mask is used many times on different inputs.